What is preventing Lucee from terminating my process when cfexecute times out?
What I'm Trying To Do
I'm attempting to write a web page that will send commands to a game server (7 Days to Die) via telnet.  I'm using Lucee and calling TST10.exe through a batch file via cfexecute.  Here is the call:
<cfexecute  name                = "mybatfile.bat"
            timeout             = "15"
            terminateOnTimeout  = "true"
            variable            = "telnetRun" />

Here is an example batch file:
[myPath]/tst10.exe /r:[myPath]\telnetScript.txt /o:[myPath]/output.txt

This is an example telnetScript file:
[serverAddr] [serverPort]
WAIT "password"
SEND "[password]"
WAIT "Press 'help' to get a list of all commands. Press 'exit' to end session."
SEND "listplayers\m"
WAIT "Total "
SEND "gettime\m"
WAIT "Day "

This works about 70% of the time.  The rest of the time, the server doesn't return anything in response to my command (or tst10 missing recording it).  Here is an example problem output file:
Please enter password:[password]

2024-06-27T14:00:10 10915.536 INF Telnet connection from: [serverAddr]:60115
2024-06-27T14:00:10 10915.536 INF Started thread TelnetClient_[serverAddr]:60115
2024-06-27T14:00:10 10915.627 INF Executing command 'gettime' by Telnet from [serverAddr]:60115
2024-06-27T14:00:10 10915.678 INF Executing command 'gettime' by Telnet from [serverAddr]:60115
2024-06-27T14:00:29 10934.827 INF DroneManager saving 0 (0 + 0)
2024-06-27T14:00:29 10934.827 INF TurretTracker saving 0 (0 + 0)
...

As you can see, the gettime command was sent and received, but the server ignored it.  This output file continues for a thousand more lines.
As tst10 doesn't appear to have any sort of time based wait or timeout attributes, I'm relying on Lucee to simply abort everything on a timeout, which is what I thought the terminateOnTimeout argument would do.
The Problem
I just looked and found about 25 instances of tst10 still running on my server, along with just as many output files that are locked from deletion, some from hours ago.  Apparently, every timeout just leaves tst10 running in the background.
What could be preventing Lucee from killing the tst10 process?  Since Lucee started the process it doesn't seem likely it's a permissions issue.
Or is there a better way of getting the process killed (taskkill won't work as all of the tst10 processes have the same task name, and some still need to continue running)?
Other Information
I'm currently running Lucee 5.3.7.47 .  I'm a bit behind, but upgrading requires testing of a very large number of legacy sites that I'd really rather avoid.
TST10 is showing version 1.0.

I think one of the processes in your command chain is dying and/or not closing out correctly, and that's both why you're not getting feedback from the app and why you have several instances running. If there's a way to do it on Windows, see if you can send a signal 0 to an executable. If the exe responds, it's good. If it doesn't, it's dead. Does your terminal client have a log you can check?
